# Shortcut for running SQL script without temp table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I have a SQL script in SQL Server Management Studio (2012) that consists of my main query and then a local temp table. I'm constantly working on the main script, but the temp table is static.

Is there a shortcut for running the script without the temp table. In other words, `F5` runs the whole script including the temp table. With the temp table, the script runs much longer.

So, is there a shortcut that allows me to run the scrip without the temp table and without having to manually select the main script every time?

Thanks

Comment: Paste your script here?

Comment: Comment those lines which you don't want to execute

Comment: The contents of the script don't really matter. There's creation of a local temp table at the top and then the main script after that (which uses the temp table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut to achieve what you want. Your options will always include editing your script:

- Set `NOEXEC ON/OFF`. Use `SET NOEXEC ON` just before your table variable and `SET NOEXEC OFF` just after.
- Comment the part you don't want to execute.
- Use `GO TO` with the appropiate label.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's a shame that there is no shortcut for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the temp table a global temp table using two #'s, for example:

```
CREATE ##mytemp TABLE (myval int)
```

**And do not close the window or drop the table**, then the connection stays open.  You can then open a new window and query, modify, or manipulate the contents of ##mytemp.

The catch is global temp tables are not private and can be queried by any other user.